# Php array_map unlink check if file exists

Tags: php, arrays, path, unlink, array-map

How do I check if the files exists in my array if I want to delete them with `array_map + unlink`:

```
// deletes all jpg files in that path

array_map('unlink', glob($path."/*.jpg"));
```

Right now if the folder does not contain any .jpg files I get an error, because there is nothing to unlink I want to catch that.

Comment: In what array??

Comment: `glob($path."/*.jpg")` creates (is) the array

Comment: And what file shoud exist there?

Comment: show all your code and error msg

Comment: What error did you get?

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be:-

```
$filepath = __DIR__ . "/your_dir_name/" ; // Make sure this path is correct
array_map('unlink', glob( "$filepath*.jpg") ?: []); // check folder is empty or not
```

Comment: But where do I check here if the files exist?

Comment: You don't need to, because `glob()` will only return files that _do_ exist.

Answer (score 0):

User in_array function to check if the value exist in array or not